# Am I the creator of this tag?

Tags: support, tags, edits

I've updated a question posted by another user, and added a tag that has never be used.

So, who is the creator of this tag? The user or me?

Comment: @CodyGray: this isn't answered at all in that FAQ.

Comment: Sure it is. It's in the very first paragraph of the answer. In fact, the very first sentence. The person who adds the tag to an existing question is the person who creates it.

Comment: I took the liberty of clarifying the presumed duplicate a bit. It said "adding to an existing question", but you can also create tags by adding them to a new question.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You created the tag with your edit, so you are the creator. If ever the tag is being used on 50 questions or more, the Taxonomy badge would be awarded to you.

Note that the *tag wiki* pages are created separately from the tag and are not in indicator of who created a tag. They are credited to the first *editor* of the wiki. If you haven't yet got the [trusted user privilege](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/trusted-user) and must suggest a tag wiki edit instead, then the first editor is the Community user, creating an empty placeholder stub the moment a suggested edit is created (so before review has completed, regardless of wether or not that edit is accepted).

Comment: I guess OP is referring [angularjs-1.6](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/angularjs-1.6). According to [this](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/41828877/revisions), isn't it community?

Comment: Is the tag creator recorded somewhere?

Comment: @Stijn: yes, for the purposes of the [Taxonomist badge](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/11/taxonomist).

Comment: @MarounMaroun: that's the tag *wiki*, not the tag itself. When a suggested edit is made for a tag wiki (because you don't yet have the required rep to edit tag wikis outright), stubs are created automatically, and that's credited to Community.

Comment: @Mistalis: yes, if this tag ends up being used on 50 questions, you should get that badge.

Comment: @MartijnPieters I created [this](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/33783750/revisions) tag, why Community wasn't involved here? Am I missing something?

Comment: @MarounMaroun: You have enough rep to edit tag wikis directly; I think Community creates one when you don't and a suggested edit is needed instead.

Comment: @MarounMaroun: I've updated my comment, the stubs were indeed created when the suggested edits were created.

Comment: @MartijnPieters It's clear now, maybe worth adding to the answer. Thanks.

Comment: Just as a comment, but here's an example. ColinD [earned the Taxonomist badge](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/11/taxonomist?userid=13792) for the [auto-value tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/auto-value), because they [created the tag editing someone else's post](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/22669792/revisions).